# Is it possible to re-sign a Mac OSX app

Tags: xcode, macos

I need to re-sign a Mac OSX app I have already built and signed. Is this possible? I need to be able to sign it with my clients certificates rather than my employers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done with [`codesign`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html). On their system, assuming their certificate is in their keychain, then can use `codesign -f -s <identity> <path>`. The `-f` option indicates that previous signatures should be replaced.

Comment: You mention their system, does this mean I need to send them my code? That is not an option at this time since the code is proprietary so says my employer. Is there a way to do this with out having to send them the editable source?

Comment: The <path> is the path to the final binary. They don't need the code, just the app bundle or executable.

Comment: Make sure that the signing is done under Mac OS X 9 or later, as the signing requirements changed then.

Comment: One last question on this, would this same process work from my own machine from with in Xcode?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "from with in Xcode." I don't think there's a way to re-sign an existing app from inside of Xcode. You can still use `codesign` of course on any machine to sign with any certificate.